# Errors Installing Ionic Framework on Windows7

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework

I have Node.js, Apache ant and Cordova installed but I keep getting this error when I try to install the Ionic framework.

Below is the error log on cmd.exe

```
C:\Windows\system32>npm install -g ionic
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "ionic"
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.20

npm ERR! shasum check failed for C:\Users\AvRazor\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-9044-1167d8eb\registry.
npmjs.org\ionic\-\ionic-1.7.14.tgz
npm ERR! Expected: af493d5df4688d917d778b0934d1739b9be6efe6
npm ERR! Actual:   24dff59ce57e08ceecf2db27f0859c143a192b56
npm ERR! From:     https://registry.npmjs.org/ionic/-/ionic-1.7.14.tgz
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Windows\system32\npm-debug.log

C:\Windows\system32>
```

Anything I am doing wrong? Is there a way to go about this? Any solutions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you clean your cache : https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/cache and try again? If the problem still exists, try installing a different version, may be ``npm install -g ionic@1.7.0``

Comment: I had already tried cleaning the cache, but let me try to install a different version then.